# Multiply slice of scipy sparse matrix without changing sparsity

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

In `scipy`, when I multiply a slice of a sparse matrix with an array containing only zeros, the result is a matrix that is less or equally sparse than before, even though it should be more or equally sparse. The same holds for setting parts of the matrix to 0 or False:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix as csr
>>> M = csr(np.random.random((8,8))>0.9)
>>> M
<8x8 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.bool_'>'
        with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> M[:,0] = False
>>> M
<8x8 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.bool_'>'
        with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> M[:,0].multiply(np.array([[False] for i in xrange(8)]))
>>> M
<8x8 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.bool_'>'
        with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

This is actually computationally expensive for large matrices, because it iterates over all cells in the slice, not just the nonzero ones.

From a mathematical / logical point of view, when multiplying a sparse matrix or vector, all empty cells are certain to remain empty as `0*x == 0`. The same holds for setting to zero: zero-cells do not need to be explicitely set to zero.

What is the best way to deal with this?

---

I am using **scipy version 0.17.0**

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "cannot" part, because for me it works without setting the first col to all zeros.

Comment: So, both the inputs are bool dtype and the first one has many cols, while the second one has just one col?

Comment: In this example, yes.

Answer (score 2):

In working with sparse matrices, changing the sparsity pattern is generally a very expensive operation, and so scipy does not do this silently.

If you want to remove explicitly stored zeros from a sparse matrix, you should use the `eliminate_zeros()` method; for example:

```
>>> M = csr(np.random.random((1000,1000))>0.9, dtype=float)
>>> M
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 99740 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> M[:, 0] *= 0
>>> M
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 99740 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> M.eliminate_zeros()
>>> M
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 99657 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Scipy *could* call the `eliminate_zeros` routine automatically after doing this kind of operation, but the developers chose to give the user more flexibility and control when doing something as expensive as changing the sparsity structure.

Comment: Not removing empty cells is one thing. I understand that is not done at all times automatically. The main problem is that empty cells become nonempty zero cells.

Comment: There's a tradeoff there as well: scipy could implicitly ignore items that are explicitly set to zero by the user, but this would cause other problems. For example in ``scipy.sparse.csgraph``, explicit zeros are used to denote graph edges that have zero weight. If you remove the ability of the user to set these, you make the package less useful. As the zen of python says, explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: ok, in my opinion, a sparse matrix should have a default value defined, i.e. `False` or `0` or `None` or `inf` or `-inf`. In your example it would then be `None` and 0 actually has a different meaning, which in my opinion is stretching the definition of sparsity a lot...

Answer (score 1):

To recreate your code (using `int` type for a more compact display):

```
In [16]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.random((8,8))>.7).astype(int)
In [17]: M
Out[17]: 
<8x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 17 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [18]: M.A
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
In [19]: M.tolil().data       # show nonzero values by row
Out[19]: 
array([list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1]), list([1, 1]), list([]),
       list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])], dtype=object)
```

Setting a row (or column) explicitly.  Note the efficiency warning:

```
In [20]: M[0,:] = 0
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:774: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
In [21]: M.tolil().data
Out[21]: 
array([list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), list([1, 1]), list([1]),
       list([1, 1]), list([]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]),
       list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])], dtype=object)
```

So yes it has set all values in the row to the specified value.  And it doesn't attempt to distinguish between setting 0s as opposed to 1s.  You can see the code used in `M.__setitem__` and `M._set_many` (this is where the efficiency warning is generated).

As @jakevpd shows, you need to explicitly tell it to eliminate excess 0s.  It does not attempt to do that during the assignment.

```
In [22]: M.eliminate_zeros()
In [23]: M.tolil().data
Out[23]: 
array([list([]), list([1, 1]), list([1]), list([1, 1]), list([]),
       list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])], dtype=object)
```

In general setting values of a matrix explicitly is discouraged, especially with `csr`.  It's not even allowed with `coo`.  `lil` is the recommended format if you need to do that.

```
In [24]: Ml = M.tolil()
In [25]: Ml[1,:] = 0
In [26]: Ml.data
Out[26]: 
array([list([]), list([]), list([1]), list([1, 1]), list([]), list([1, 1]),
       list([1, 1]), list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])], dtype=object)
```

`lil` does take care to eliminate 0s.

Multiplication of a row by an array of 0s does not change the sparsity.  Nor does it act in-place.  It produces a new matrix:

```
In [29]: M[1,:].multiply(np.zeros((1,8)))
Out[29]: 
<1x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [30]: _.A
Out[30]: array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [31]: M[1,:].A
Out[31]: array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Multiplication with a sparse matrix does eliminate 0s (again, not in-place):

```
In [32]: M[1,:].multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(np.zeros((1,8))))
Out[32]: 
<1x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

(Notice also the different in format between `Out[29]` and `Out[32]`.)

As a general rule, multiplication, both element-wise and matrix, is the most efficient operation with `csr` matrices, especially if the `other` is also sparse.  In fact row/column sums are performed with matrix multiplication, as is `advanced` indexing.